# Used function argument to access JSON Array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a basic function taking an argument. I will use this argument to as index to access the array in JSON file. I want to take advantage of this argument instead of hard-coded inside the function. However, for some reasons, javascript is not return me the right value.

```
var obj = {
    "first":[
        ["aaaaa"],
        ["bbbbb"],
        ["ccccc"],
        ["ddddd"],
        ["eeeee"]                   
    ]
}
```

I have a javascript function to access the file.

```
function addElement(ID) {
    console.log(obj.ID);
}
```

and now if I use

```
addElement("first"); //this return me undefined.
```

I do not want to explicitly mention `obj.first` in order to access the right JSON object. I would like to make it more generic so that the method can be re-used. Am I missing anything here?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript supports both dot notation and a property name *literal* (`obj.foo`), and brackets notation and a property name *string* (`obj["foo"]`).* In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression.

So you'd need brackets notation, not dot notation:

```
function addElement(ID) {
    console.log(obj[ID]);
}
```

`obj.ID` accesses the property `ID`. `obj[ID]` accesses the property whose name is the string from the variable `ID`.

---

* Just for completeness: In ES6, it will support property name `Symbol`s in brackets notation as well, but that's not relevant to your code.

Comment: omg..thanks for your answer..didnt this is just a property of JS..Thanks!